# Is is possible to use IOCP (or other API) in Reactor-style operations?

Tags: winapi, sockets, select, iocp, reactor

Is there any scalable Win32 API (like IOCP not like select) that gives you reactor style
operations on sockets? AFAIK IOCP allows you to receive notification on completed operations
like data read or written (proactor) but I'm looking for reactor style of operations: I
need to get notification when the socket is readable or writable (reactor).

Something similar to epoll, kqueue, `/dev/poll` ?

Is there such API in Win32? If so where can I find a manual on it?

** Clarification:** I need `select` like api for sockets that is as scalable as IOCP, or I'm looking for a way to use IOCP in reactor like operations.

**Even more clarification:** IOCP allows you to receive an notification on completion of given operation. For example:

```
WSARecv(buffer,...); // start reading
WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(...); // wait when read is done
```

So I get notication **after** operation is done -- proctor style of operations.

What I need is something like that:

```
WSARecv( NOTHING ); // start waiting for readability (not actual read)
WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(...); // wait until read would not block
// Now WSARecv would not block
WSARecv(buffer,...); // now actual non-blocking read
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to design your code in the 'reactor' style? Why can't you simply use IOCP ? it works well and the model is easy to understand once you spend a little time with it.

Comment: I want to create a **tiny** cross platform select-like `C` library that would use epoll on Linux, kqueue on FreeBSD, `/dev/poll` on Solaris and HP-UX, IOCP on Windows, poll on generic UNIX and select on all others. All these APIs with exception of IOCP are reactor style APIs, so I prefer to stick to them. Another issue is operation cancellation is more complex in proactor style APIs and very problematic under XP and below with IOCP. (And yes I'm familiar with ASIO, Libevent and others... So do not suggest them)

Comment: Accept that, since it's cross platform and you're making compromises, it's never going to be as performant as it could be and simply use select on Windows and deal with the handle limit using additional threads if necessary...

Comment: s/clearification/clarification/g please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

I've checked Boost.Asio sources that do have reactor style operations and use IOCP. For all reactor style operations separate thread with `select` is used instead of IOCP.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [WSAAsyncSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741540(v=VS.85).aspx) API. It uses a Windows message queue to signal that a handle is read for read/write/whatever, so it doesn't have the concurrency benefits of IOCP, but it allows you to implement a standard reactor pattern without having a limit to the number of handles (like `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`).

Comment: It really looks like WSAAsyncSelect is what you want. Can you please explain how it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, isn't Reactor pattern where the thread blocks waiting on multiple event sources? That would be select(), which windows supports. The Proactor pattern is where there is a single callback per call, that you can do via ReadFileEx/WriteFileEx.

Comment: Yes, select like operations are what I need but select is not as 
scalable as epoll/kqueue.

Comment: I think WaitForMultipleObjectsEx will do the same thing for you as select, though not sure if it will address your perf concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing zero nNumberOfBytesToRead to, for example ReadFile(socket_fd, ..)?

Maybe it will help to get the "read ready" event.